# Как в Red 5 pro server реализовать рестриминг на сервер?

Tags: java, сервер, red5

Всем привет. Начал работать с red5pro server и попытался сделать рестрим с удаленного стрима, но ничего не получается. Так же пытался увидеть стрим с VLC плеера, но так же все пусто. Но когда раздаю стрим с телефона то все читается и записывается. Может кто работал с red5 и может подсказать в какую сторону копать и как можно реализовать рестриминг на сервер. Прилагаю сделанный код. Спасибо

```
public class Restreamer extends MultiThreadedApplicationAdapter {
RTSPCameraClient test;

public boolean  appStart(IScope scope) {
    super.appStart(scope);
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {     
            log.info("Hello from appStart");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            // imported from red5pro jar.           

            test = new RTSPCameraClient();

            test.setHost("192.168.1.162");
            test.setPort(8554);
            test.setContextPath("context");
            test.setStreamName("stream1");
            test.setClient(new ClientHandlerDemo());
            test.run();

            Thread thread = new Thread(test);

            ClientBroadcastStream broadcastStream = ConnectorShell.Connect(scope, "stream1");

            broadcastStream.start();
            try {
                broadcastStream.saveAs("stream1.flv", false);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } 

            broadcastStream.startPublishing();

            thread.start();

            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            int time = 0;
            while (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime < 60000) {
                MediaPacket mp = test.getPackets().poll();
                if (mp != null)  {
                    if (mp.frame instanceof VideoData) {
                        VideoData vd = (VideoData) mp.frame;
                        vd.setTimestamp(time);
                        broadcastStream.dispatchEvent(vd);
                        time += 135;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Time broadcast video is " + time);
            test.stop();
            try {
                thread.join(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ConnectorShell.Close(broadcastStream); 

        }
    }).start();
    return true;
}

@Override
public void streamBroadcastStart(IBroadcastStream stream){
    log.info("Hello from streamBroadcastStart");
    try {
       ClientBroadcastStream bStream = (ClientBroadcastStream) stream;
       if(!bStream.isRecording()) {
          bStream.saveAs(bStream.getPublishedName(), false);
       }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void stopRecording(IBroadcastStream stream){
    try
    {
       ClientBroadcastStream bStream = (ClientBroadcastStream) stream;
       if(bStream.isRecording()) {
          bStream.stopRecording();
       }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Что это за язык?

Comment: Java, серверная часть red5 пишется именно на нем